# C# Charting: Horizontal Y axis title alignment

Tags: c#, charts, formatting

I am plotting a chart that displays time by force. The force units on the Y axis are "µN." The y axis title is automatically vertical, however this distorts how the special characters are displayed. I was able to turn the orientation of the Y axis title so now the characters are being displayed correctly, except now there is so much empty space around the title. I have tried turning off Margins and that didn't change anything. Any ideas on how to make the Axis title take up less space?

[image: The two axis titles]

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the following is a good solution:

```
Title title = new Title("µN");
title.Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
this.chart1.Titles.Add(title);
```

The result:

[image]